# Deploying Firebase Emulator on EC2 Instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, firebase-authentication, nginx-reverse-proxy, firebase-tools

I have a deployed test environment - https://footystats.dev/#/features that I want connecting to the firebase emulator suite for the authentication service.

However when trying to use the UI on port 4000 I am having issues with 3 network requests:

1. http://172.31.40.139:9099/identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/projects/play-on-dev/accounts:query
2. http://172.31.40.139:9099/identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v2/projects/play-on-dev/tenants
3. http://172.31.40.139:9099/emulator/v1/projects/play-on-dev/config

However this call is working:

http://costagiannakopoulos.com/api/config

[image]

Please can anyone advise if I am missing something easy as Iv wasted hours and seem to be going round in circles.

When I run firebase locally so everything is running on localhost it works as expected.

In my attempt to get this working I have set up an EC2 instance with NGINX running as a reverse proxy.

I have created the following domain and subdomain:

1. http://costagiannakopoulos.com
2. https://auth.costagiannakopoulos.com

My firebase.json is configured like this:

```
{
  "emulators": {
    "auth": {
      "host": "172.31.40.139",
      "port": 9099
    },
    "ui": {
      "enabled": true,
      "host": "172.31.40.139",
      "port": 4000
    },
    "hub": {
      "enabled": true,
      "host": "172.31.40.139",
      "port": 4400
    },
    "logging": {
      "enabled": true,
      "host": "172.31.40.139",
      "port": 4501
    },
    "singleProjectMode": true
  }
}
```

The IP host is pointing to the private ip on the EC2 instance.

My NGING config for emulator UI looks like this:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name costagiannakopoulos.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://172.31.40.139:4000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

And the NGINX config for authentication looks like this:

```
`server {
    listen 80;
    server_name auth.costagiannakopoulos.com;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name auth.costagiannakopoulos.com;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/auth.costagiannakopoulos.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/auth.costagiannakopoulos.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://172.31.40.139:9099;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}`
```

When hitting this url http://costagiannakopoulos.com/api/config I get this response:

```
    {
    "auth": {
        "host": "172.31.40.139",
        "listen": [
            {
                "address": "172.31.40.139",
                "family": "IPv4",
                "port": 9099
            }
        ],
        "name": "auth",
        "port": 9099
    },
    "hub": {
        "host": "172.31.40.139",
        "listen": [
            {
                "address": "172.31.40.139",
                "family": "IPv4",
                "port": 4400
            }
        ],
        "name": "hub",
        "port": 4400
    },
    "logging": {
        "host": "172.31.40.139",
        "listen": [
            {
                "address": "172.31.40.139",
                "family": "IPv4",
                "port": 4501
            }
        ],
        "name": "logging",
        "port": 4501
    },
    "ui": {
        "host": "172.31.40.139",
        "listen": [
            {
                "address": "172.31.40.139",
                "family": "IPv4",
                "port": 4000
            }
        ],
        "name": "ui",
        "pid": 26141,
        "port": 4000
    }
}
```

Thanks
Costa